# Float only printing whole numbers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, sdk

Why is it that when I run this code in a loop, only whole numbers are printed in the console?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
        zombieSpeed[i] = (((arc4random()%40)+2)/7);
        NSLog(@"%f", zombieSpeed[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here

```
zombieSpeed[i] = (((arc4random()%40)+2)/7);
```

instead of 40, 2, 7 you should use 40.0, 2.0, 7.0

Also make sure that ZombieSpeed is of float type

Comment: Yes, the problem is it is doing integer arithmetic, since none of the components of the expression are of a floating point type, the processor can save work by doing the arithmetic on integers only

Comment: Wow thanks I never came across that before! Oh and of course it is a float

Answer (score 2):

This line needs to use `Float` values (40.0, 2.0, 7.0)

```
zombieSpeed[i] = (((arc4random()%40)+2)/7);
```

Answer (score 1):

The division is an integer division, use explicit decimal point as 40.0 or typecast, so that at least one operand is floating point, which upcasts the entire expression to be evaluated as floating point. Make sure that any left hand side variable to which you assign the computer value is of floating point type with equal or greater width (to preserve the precision).